# Do SOAP UI support JCEKS keystore?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, soapui, soap-client

I have generated a  JCEKS key-store with 3DES(DESEDE) secret key for our SOAP UI Project.But when I try to import that key store in our SOAP UI project,we are getting this following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec cannot be cast to java.security.PrivateKey
```

Already tried to find any related solution regarding this issue but no good answer was found.

Now my question is can we use JCEKS key-store for SOAP-UI Project ? or only JKS keystore is supported?

Similar link are here

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Support-for-signature-using-secretkey/td-p/33846

Comment: If it can find out that the stored key isn't a `PrivateKey` then it must already have parsed the `KeyStore` instance itself. So I guess it can, it just expects an (RSA) private key, not a 3DES key *it seems*.